# How to group by a hash key with sum and average

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with keys and i want to group them (by week number or month number) with a subhash which contain average and sum

example with week group by
from

```
{
  "2020-08-01"=>139.00878400877275,
  "2020-08-02"=>125.1707728336493,
  "2020-08-03"=>125.71265007026805,
  "2020-08-04"=>125.70456541451202,
  "2020-08-05"=>125.96825529230075
}
```

to

```
{
  "30" => {
    "sum" => 139.00878400877275,
    "avg" => 139.00878400877275
  },
  "31" => {
    "sum" => 502.556243611,
    "avg" => 125.639060903
  }
}
```

I've try with a group by to obtain a week regroupment, but I don't know how to reduce into sum and avg.

```
hash.group_by { |k,_| Date.parse(k).strftime("%U").to_i }
# => {30=>[["2020-08-01", 139.00878400877275]], 31=>[["2020-08-02", 125.1707728336493], ["2020-08-03", 125.71265007026805], ["2020-08-04", 125.70456541451202], ["2020-08-05", 125.96825529230075]]}
```

Comment: `Date.parse "is a method that may have unexpected consequences, so use it with care;  preferrably, use strptime whenever possible" #=> #<Date: 2020-05-01 ((2458971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"2020-08-01"=>139.008, "2020-08-02"=>125.170, "2020-08-03"=>125.712,
        "2020-08-04"=>125.704, "2020-08-05"=>125.968}
```

```
require 'date'

data.each_with_object({}) do |(date_str,v),h|      
  (h[Date.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').cweek.to_s] ||= []) << v
end.transform_values do |arr|
  tot = arr.sum
  { "sum"=>tot, "avg"=> tot.fdiv(arr.size).round(3) }
end
  #=> {"31"=>{"sum"=>264.178, "avg"=>132.089},
  #    "32"=>{"sum"=>377.384, "avg"=>125.795}}
```

The first step is as follows:

```
data.each_with_object({}) do |(date_str,v),h|      
  (h[Date.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').cweek.to_s] ||= []) << v
end
  #=> {"31"=>[139.008, 125.17], "32"=>[125.712, 125.704, 125.968]}
```

See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [Date#cweek](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cweek).

It is then a simple matter to convert the arrays to hashes with keys `"sum"` and `"avg"`. See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

It is even easier to compute the values by month, as no `Date` methods are needed:

```
data.each_with_object({}) do |(date_str,v),h|      
  (h[date_str[5,2]] ||= []) << v
end.transform_values do |arr|
  tot = arr.sum
  { "sum"=>tot, "avg"=> tot.fdiv(arr.size).round(3) }
end
  #=> {"08"=>{"sum"=>641.562, "avg"=>128.312}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the groupings:

```rb
grouped.transform_values do |date_vals|
  _dates, vals = date_vals.transpose
  { "sum" => vals.sum, "avg" => vals.sum / vals.size }
end
```

and if it helps you understand better, split out in two steps:

```rb
grouped_datevals = grouped.transform_values(&:transpose)

grouped_datevals.transform_values do |_dates, vals|
  { "sum" => vals.sum, "avg" => vals.sum.to_f / vals.size }
end
```

Comment: You can use [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) instead of `reduce`, which s more descriptive. I would also save the sum in a variable first otherwise you're calculating the sum twice.

Comment: Ah nice, didn't know `sum` was added to core. Calculating the sum twice isn't a big deal, it's not worth the hit to concision here IMO.